# Magento 2 - Add Product Search functionality using Ajax in Custom Admin Form

Tags: magento2, product, ajax, search, adminform

I had created an admin form in Magento 2. I had taken a text field for the product search. I want to search for a product by entering Product `Name` / `SKU` / `ID` in the text field. How could I do it? I want to search product by adding custom ajax search functionality?

Please find the attached screenshot for my custom admin form.
[image]

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance..!

Comment: did you find any solution?